# Why does this extra WHERE clause not return what I am expecting?

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

I have 2 database tables, one is a calendar filled only with dates into the future and another with stock allocations which have a quantity, date and product ID.

The big picture is that I need a table which displays a list of dates with any stock allocation quantities grouped as a single total beside each date.

This is the calendar with the dates only for July:

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
    `datefield` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

LOCK TABLES `calendar` WRITE; 

INSERT INTO `calendar` (`datefield`) VALUES 
('2012-07-01'),('2012-07-02'),('2012-07-03'),('2012-07-04'),('2012-07-05'),
('2012-07-06'),('2012-07-07'),('2012-07-08'),('2012-07-09'),('2012-07-10'),
('2012-07-11'),('2012-07-12'),('2012-07-13'),('2012-07-14'),('2012-07-15'),
('2012-07-16'),('2012-07-17'),('2012-07-18'),('2012-07-19'),('2012-07-20'), 
('2012-07-21'),('2012-07-22'),('2012-07-23'),('2012-07-24'),('2012-07-25'),
('2012-07-26'),('2012-07-27'),('2012-07-28'),('2012-07-29'),('2012-07-30'),
('2012-07-31'); 

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

And this is the stock allocation table:

```
CREATE TABLE `stock_allocation` ( 
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `product_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

LOCK TABLES `stock_allocation` WRITE; 

INSERT INTO `stock_allocation` (`ID`, `product_ID`, `date`, `quantity`) VALUES
(1,3,'2012-07-30',50),
(2,3,'2012-07-26',40),
(3,3,'2012-07-26',100), 
(4,3,'2012-07-02',200),
(5,3,'2012-07-01',134); 

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The query I have run which gives me the closest to what I need is:

```
SELECT 
    calendar.datefield AS date_allocation,
    IFNULL(SUM(stock_allocation.quantity),0) AS total_allocation 
FROM 
    stock_allocation 
RIGHT JOIN 
    calendar ON DATE(stock_allocation.date) = calendar.datefield 
WHERE 
    calendar.datefield >= '2012-12-01' AND 
    calendar.datefield <='2012-12-31' 
GROUP BY 
    date_allocation
```

So this gives something like this which is nearly what I need:

```
    +-----------------+------------------+
    | date_allocation | total_allocation |
    +-----------------+------------------+
    | 2012-07-01      |              134 |
    | 2012-07-02      |              200 |
    | 2012-07-03      |                0 |
    | 2012-07-04      |                0 |
    | 2012-07-05      |                0 |
    | 2012-07-06      |                0 |
    | 2012-07-07      |                0 |
     etc etc
    | 2012-07-22      |                0 |
    | 2012-07-23      |                0 |
    | 2012-07-24      |                0 |
    | 2012-07-25      |                0 |
    | 2012-07-26      |              140 |
    | 2012-07-27      |                0 |
    | 2012-07-28      |                0 |
    | 2012-07-29      |                0 |
    | 2012-07-30      |               50 |
    | 2012-07-31      |                0 |
    +-----------------+------------------+
```

But I want to add in this final WHERE clause to make the query:

```
SELECT 
    calendar.datefield AS date_allocation,
    IFNULL(SUM(stock_allocation.quantity),0) AS total_allocation 
FROM 
    stock_allocation 
RIGHT JOIN 
    calendar ON DATE(stock_allocation.date) = calendar.datefield 
WHERE 
    calendar.datefield >= '2012-07-01' AND 
    calendar.datefield <='2012-07-31' AND 
    stock_allocation.product_ID = '3' 
GROUP BY 
    date_allocation
```

But this output returns:

```
    +-----------------+------------------+
    | date_allocation | total_allocation |
    +-----------------+------------------+
    | 2012-07-26      |              140 |
    | 2012-07-30      |               50 |
    +-----------------+------------------+
```

I hope you can understand what I need - given the sample date included I expect the two queries to return basically the same thing because the productID for the sample stock_allocation data is always 3.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, you will want to change your filtering criteria to be based on the `product_id` field instead of the `ID` field.

However, if you still want all of the calendar dates to show up while only performing the summation on rows where `product_id = 3`, you would add the `AND product_id = 3` to the `LEFT JOIN` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause. That way, calendar rows where there are no joins where `product_id = 3` are still kept in the final result-set instead of filtered out(which the WHERE clause does):

```
SELECT 
    a.datefield AS date_allocation,
    IFNULL(SUM(b.quantity),0) AS total_allocation 
FROM
    calendar a
LEFT JOIN
    stock_allocation b 
    ON a.datefield = b.date AND
       b.product_id = 3
WHERE 
    a.datefield BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31'
GROUP BY 
    a.datefield
```

Comment: This is also very helpful indeed and does exactly what I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Change `AND stock_allocation.ID` to `AND stock_allocation.product_ID`.

Comment: Sorry - made a mistake - see my comment to @gotuskar

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `stock_allocation.product_ID = '3'` instead of `stock_allocation.ID = '3'`. stock_allocation.ID will always be unique, you will only have 1 entry with value '3'

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the second query and its output now. My question is still the same but with corrected query and output.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your query doesn't return the rows is that the WHERE clause is eliminating all those rows from calendar where there isn't a matching row from stock_allocation. That WHERE clause is defeating the OUTER JOIN, making it work like an INNER JOIN.

You want that predicate in the `ON` clause, rather than the `WHERE` clause.

That will get you all of the calendar dates with all the zeros you want.

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    calendar.datefield AS date_allocation,
    IFNULL(SUM(stock_allocation.quantity),0) AS total_allocation 
FROM 
    stock_allocation 
RIGHT JOIN 
    calendar 
ON 
    stock_allocation.date = calendar.datefield 
    AND stock_allocation.product_ID = '3' 
WHERE 
    calendar.datefield >= '2012-07-01' AND 
    calendar.datefield <='2012-07-31' AND 
GROUP BY 
    date_allocation
```

NOTE: You don't need a DATE() function around the `stock_allocation.date` column, the datatype of that column is already DATE.

Comment: This is very helpful indeed and does exactly what I need. Thank you very much.